# How to get the number of active clusters in a multi-cluster warehouse over time?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to get the chart or graph the number of running clusters ( in multi-cluster warehouse) over time for the load survey.

I think it can by using the `account_usage` view, but I can't.
For example, I made below code, but it is imperfect because the view has not the number of running clusters but identification number for each cluster.

```
SELECT
    TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(timestamp),1,16)) AS timestamp,
    COUNT(DISTINCT warehouse_id)                      AS cluster_number
FROM
    SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_EVENTS_HISTORY
WHERE
    warehouse_name = 'COMPUTE_WH'
    AND
    timestamp >= DATEADD(H, -12, current_timestamp)
GROUP BY timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

If you know something, please answer my question.

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by "transion" as it's not a word, as far as I'm aware? Also, what do you mean by a cluster of a warehouse - the number of clusters running for a multi-cluster  warehouse, or something else? Which of the warehouse events are you trying to query and why - if you include every event (start, stop, suspend, etc.) then the result is likely to be meaningless? Maybe if you updated your question with some sample scenarios it would be clearer what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

You can infer this by looking at cluster number in query history. AFAICT the number always goes up incrementally so you can take the max number to find current total.

Technically you should split the query durations across minutes instead of assuming it finishes in the `start_minute` but this is good enough for a quick look at cluster count.

```sql
select WAREHOUSE_SIZE wh_size,
       DATE_TRUNC('minute',start_time) start_minute,
       MAX(CLUSTER_NUMBER) clusters,
       COUNT(QUERY_ID) queries,
       ROUND(AVG(QUEUED_OVERLOAD_TIME/TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME)*100.00,1) queue_pct
from snowflake.account_usage.query_history
where database_name = 'MY_DB'
  and execution_status = 'SUCCESS'
  and query_type NOT IN ('SHOW','ALTER_WAREHOUSE_RESUME','ALTER_WAREHOUSE_SUSPEND','ALTER_SESSION')
  and start_time >= '2024-01-01 00:00:00 -0000'
  and warehouse_name = 'MY_WH'
group by all
order by start_minute 
limit 100
;
```

| WH_SIZE | START_MINUTE | CLUSTERS | QUERY_CNT | QUEUE_PCT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:00:00 | 9 | 42 | 0.0 |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:01:00 | 9 | 31 | 0.0 |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:02:00 | 9 | 39 | 0.0 |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:03:00 | 9 | 31 | 0.0 |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:04:00 | 9 | 30 | 0.0 |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:05:00 | 5 | 37 | 52.6 |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:06:00 | 8 | 18 | 72.6 |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:07:00 | 9 | 23 | 59.5 |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:08:00 | 10 | 39 | 47.7 |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:09:00 | 10 | 43 | 46.2 |
| Medium | 2024-01-01 01:10:00 | 3 | 1 | 34.5 |

Comment: Answering this one for myself so I can find it in a search engine when I forget where I saved it. :D